# Using two dictionary keys (key 1 _and_ 2) to determine value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

I have a Python script that will read two bytes out of a preexisting binary. One byte determines a Device Type and the next determines a Sub-Device Type. Both together defines the overall device.

For instance:

```
x41 and x01 = Printer
x43 and x01 = Audio Device
```

My code will need to find both x41 and x01 for there to be a Printer, for instance.

I thought about doing this with a dictionary, but I think it means two keys per value and doesn't quite look so trivial to implement (at least for my skillset).

Is a dictionary a good approach? Or would something else be better?

Comment: You can have a key made up of two values. Use a tuple. e.g. `mydict[(a,b)]=c`

Comment: I think it would be better to use nested dictionary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said in comments, two approachs are possible:

```
Devices={(0x41,0x01) : 'Printer' , (0x43,0x01) : 'Audio Device', ...}
```

or

```
ComputerDevices={ 0x41 : 'Printer' , 0x43 : 'Audio Device', ...}
KitchenDevices={ 0x41 : 'Roaster' , 0x26 : 'Oven', ...}
...
Devices = {0x01: ComputerDevices , 0x02 :KitchenDevices, ...}
```

You can also concatenate your bytes : `key =bytes([0x43,0x01])` and use it for dictionary key.

Comment: Could you say a little more about how to concatenate the bytes I read? If I grab 43, then 41, I'd concatenate them into a key... how?

Comment: Depend on how you grab them. suppose you get them from a binary file : a=read(1),..., b= read(1),  then code =bytes([a,b]) is a compact and unique key. if they are contigous code =read(2) is ok.  Bytes are immutable and usable as dict keys. so you can add in dict by Devices[code]='Printer' .

Answer (score 1):

There are pros and cons to using a single-level dictionary to represent this data. The implementation, however, is trivial: use a tuple as the dicitonary key.

```
d = { (0x41,0x01) : "Printer", (0x43,0x01) : "Audio Device" }
print "The device is:", d[major_byte,minor_byte]
```

As an alternative, you can use nested dictionaries:

```
d = { 0x41 : { 0x01 : "Printer" }, 0x43 : { 0x01 : "Audio Device" } }
print "The device is:", d[major_byte][minor_byte]
```

Which one you want to use depends upon your precise requirements.